# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=-1 \implies \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x^2-4)}{x-2}=-4$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=-1$, then $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x^2-4)}{x-2}=-4$.

I've tried everything, substitution, limit composition, etc.

Anyone could help me to solve this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{f(x^2-4)}{x-2} = (x+2)\cdot \dfrac{f(x^2-4)}{x^2-4}$, and then use the result above.

Comment: Fine, I hope it helped.